# MySQL where column contains part of string of another column

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I want to `join` 2 tables in my database.

Table `a` has this field:

`Course Series` which contains string like this:

"ABC Course xxxx - ....."

Table `b` has this field:

`NAME OF COURSE` which contains string like this:

"Course Series "xxxx":....."

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c013a)

How I can write my `where` clause in order to compare the xxxx part of the strings?

Comment: Please frame SQL questions with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I added sql fiddle